# jquery xml data retriving issue in ie

Tags: jquery

i am getting the online xml data using jquery. for getting online information i am suing ph. and i am sending the information using $get function like this :

```
var timeObject = { 
                getNewYorkLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
                getLondonLocalTime : 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
                getChennaiLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
                getBangaloreLocalTime:'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'
                }

            var i = 0;

            for(var x in timeObject){
                if(timeObject.hasOwnProperty(x)){

                    var cityTime = timeObject[x];

                    $.get(cityTime, function(data) {
                        var myDate = $(data).find('localtime').text();
                        var cityId = parseInt($(data).find('latitude').text());
                        var time = new Date(myDate);
                        var hours = time.getHours();
                        var minutes = time.getMinutes();
                        var seconds = time.getSeconds();
                        hours = hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours;
                        alert(data);
                        i++;
                        var num = i;
                        showTime (num,cityId,hours,minutes,seconds);    

                    });



            }   
        }
```

for example, in case if i alert to get the 'cityId',myDate, i am getting the answer. but internet explorer shows blank. any one can tell me what is wrong with my code? or any way to solve this issue?

Note: if i alert just 'data' i am getting the xml information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the content type to "text/xml" when you send back the response. IE is know to ignore xml if the content type is not set correctly.

Use the following to identify your current content type. Make sure it is **"text/xml"**

```
getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
```

In your php add the following before you send back the response.

```
HttpResponse::setContentType ( "text/xml" );
```

Add "xml" as a datatype to your "get" method as the last parameter.

```
 $.get(cityTime, function(data) {
                       ...... //removed other code for ease of readability

                    }, "xml" );
```

Read up on these here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get
http://php.net/manual/en/function.httpresponse-setcontenttype.php